# Where I can find a template for a minimum ios app?

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm not an ios developer, but I need to do some work on ios app.

Basically I need to build a minimum ios app with no UI at all. I just need a function stub that when launching the app, the function is executed. I will use it to run some native C/C++ code to benchmark the performance on iOS devices. Is there a template that I can use?

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with the new project templates provided by Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

You can simple create a new `Single View App` and then remove the `Main Interface` (and `Launch Screen File` too) in the target setting

Do your work (launch your function) in `AppDelegate > application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

[image]